Superposition - Mesh analysis
I am given this circuit:

I try to calculate the current Ix using superpoisition and mesh analysis. First I kill the 12V voltage source and use mesh analysis in the following way (find the mesh equations by KVL):

So I get i1_1 = around -13mA. Next I do the same, just open the current source:

So I get i1_2 = around -1mA. Then according to superposition Ix = i1_1 + i1_2 = around -14mA¨
However when I simulate the circuit in multisim I measure around -6.51mA:

What am I missing here?

What program are you using to calculate with?

I use Multisim for simulation

The equation part

MathCad for equations

I worked out a solution and got the same as your simulator. It would appear you are maybe ignoring where you are going from higher to lower potential as well as voltage polarity in your equation.
Ultimately you have the right idea but if you are going to oppose the polarity of your voltage source in your mesh currents you will have to negate the voltage.
Lastly even though i drew my currents in the opposite orientation to yours the answers work out the same. I just prefered this way.

Also i am sorry i accidentally wrote ohms when solving for current after doing RREF. should say [3/2125, 1/4250]A nor ohms

This was very, very useful
